# Single Sign-on between Zend and Yii Framework applications

Tags: security, zend-framework, yii, single-sign-on, cas

We have 3 websites running on Yii and Zend frameworks and we would like to implement some form of centralized authentication system (similar to what Google does). I have never done this before. I was wondering if anyone knows any open-source solution that might help. I stumbled across CAS from http://www.jasig.org earlier and I am not sure if it is the best solution.

I would appreciate any kind of insight on this (including security risks and best practices maybe).

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to roll your own or do you want to use one of the big ones? Google, Facebook or OpenId...

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to create my own or use an open source one that I can integrate into my system (if that's not too risky to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth / OpenID should do the trick for you.

http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Just one question before I close the discussion: You see, I want to have my own point of authentication for several applications (not really authenticating users through Google or Facebook). These are existing users, but I would like to allow them to use different applications, through a Single Sign-on from one access point. My question is: Is OAuth something I can install to create myself that access point or does it allow users to login through Google, Facebook ... ? Ive searched everywhere, but I could not get this question answered. Thank you